# Set desktop color in Windows 10 to white?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, themes

Is it possible to set the color of the desktop in Windows 10 to "white"?
There is only a small set of predefined colors without white.
Ok, I can just use a blank white JPEG. But is this really the way Microsoft intended to deal with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying this one, I found another solution in the Microsoft community. Just wanted to share it:

- Open a run prompt with WIN+R
- Paste: control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper
- Select "Solid Colors"
- Click "More". This should lead to an RGB input.

Worked perfectly for me and gave me a few additional options.

Answer (score 4):

- Open Regedit
- Navigate to HKCU\Control Panel\Colors\Background
- Modify setting = 255 255 255
- Reboot (or logout-login)

Comment: Works perfect :-)